# facebook comments, looping through JSON

Tags: jquery, facebook, json

I am trying to get comments using the FB API. The json I get back is correct but I am having trouble looping through the json.

Here is my JS :-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.showcomments a').click(function() {

        var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
        id = id[1];

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/comments?access_token=foobar",
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function(comments) {

                $.each(comments.data, function(i, comment){
                    alert('<h3>'+comment.from.name+'</h3><p>'+comment.message+'</p>');
                });

            }
        });

   }); 
});
```

I think the problem is with the comments.data

firebug gives the following:-

```
a is undefined
[Break On This Error] (function(a,b){function cv(a){return f...ndexOf(".")>=0&&(i=h.split("."),h=i.
```

Cheers for any help

Comment: What do you see when you put `console.log(comments)` at the start of the `success` callback?

Comment: { "data": [ { "id": "foobar", "from": { "name": "foobar", "id": "foobar" }, "message": "foobar", "created_time": "2011-11-08T14:31:22+0000" } ], "paging": { "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/foobar/comments?access_token=foobar&limit=25&offset=25" } }

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/bFY6y/ -- seems to work fine here.

Comment: Strange huh... I'm using the latest version of jquery (v1.7)

Answer (score 0):

try using
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.showcomments a').click(function() {

```
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-');
    id = id[1];

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/comments?access_token=foobar",
        type: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        complete: function(comments) {

            $.each(comments.data, function(i, comment){
                alert('<h3>'+comment.from.name+'</h3><p>'+comment.message+'</p>');
            });

        }
    });
```

}); 
});

complete instead of success